# Find and update the current live program in mysql with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table in mysql db which contains a list of TV Programs of this week. It is something like this.

```
----------------------------------------------
start_time,        tv_program_name    isLive
2013-01-19 17:00   sports news
2013-01-19 18:30   NBA....

......

------------------------------------------------
```

I want to use SQL to find out the current tv program by compare the start_time with now(), and mark the current tv program in db with isLive = 1

I try to use the sql

```
-------------
SELECT * 
FROM tv_programs
ORDER BY ABS( TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
MINUTE , start_time, NOW( ) ) ) ASC 
-------------
```

But it is not the right solution because it only return the `tv_program` which is nearest to the current, not the live tv program that it is playing now.

Can anyone show me some light on this problem?

Comment: You have no `end_time`, so how is it known whether a program has ended? Is there _always_ a program running?

Comment: it is easier to query the list if you have end time.

Comment: Is there only one channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tv_programs
WHERE start_time <= NOW()
ORDER BY start_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I think it should be "update xxxx" but I think this answer is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an update query?

```
UPDATE tv_programmess
SET isLive = 1
WHERE start_time = Now()
```